# Routing from Laravel to AngularJS existing in another folder

Tags: angularjs, laravel

I have two separate folders for my project, one has Laravel for backend part named as 'backend' and another has angularjs for frontend part named as `frontend`. My question is how to routing from `laravel` to `angularjs`?

I tried to do

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index.html'); // 'index.html' is located at /project/frontend
});

Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api'), function() {
        Route::resource('todos', 'TodoController');
});
```

in

```
/project/backend/routes/web.php
```

and I also changed `paths` in

```
/project/backend/config/view.php
```

to

```
'paths' => array(__DIR__.'/../frontend'),
```

This gives me

```
InvalidArgumentException View [index.html] not found
```

I think it is because I was not able to locate the right index.html file. I am new to Laravel and AngularJS, please help me!

Comment: You can't route a backend application to an frontend application. The frontend is calling the routes.

Comment: Maybe I didn't use the word correctly...but do you know how to do that if they are in two folders?  https://scotch.io/tutorials/create-a-laravel-and-angular-single-page-comment-application This link shows how to do it if backend and frontend are in the same folder.